# How to use IS_MEMBER('AAD_GROUPNAME') in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

We are implementing row level security in Azure Synapse Analytics and we want to check if user is member of specific Azure AAD group, user can access data. As per [documentation][1]

[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-member-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 it says this function only check windows group. Is there any work around or ETA when this features will be available?

We tried using below query but it always returns **NULL**

`SELECT IS_MEMBER('AAD_Group_Name')`

Answer (score 1):

The document you have shared clearly mentioned that  `IS_MEMBER` function is not supported for Azure Active Directory Groups.

You can [raise the feature request here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/79b1327d-d925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4).

Alternatively, you can check this official document about [How to set up access control for your Azure Synapse workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control). This will help you to understand and implement **control access to a Microsoft Azure Synapse workspace using Azure roles, Azure Synapse roles, SQL permissions, and Git permissions.**

Comment: I know it is not supported but we want to migrate existing ADX code to Synapse. So is there any workaround do implement exact functionality?