# How to Access Azure AD Security Group In Microsoft Fabric Lakehouse SQL analytics endpoint

Tags: azure-synapse, microsoft-fabric

Can I access AD Security group in Microsoft Fabric Lakehouse SQL analytics endpoint? I tried IS_MEMBER ('AnyGroupName')  function. But it didn't work. It returned "NULL". Do you have any idea? My aim is to create RLS security in SQL with Security Groups.

Below link says for IS_MEMBER function:  "... current user is a member of a database role or a Windows domain group."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-member-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

I have been searching for five days and still have nothing.

I found [How to use IS_MEMBER('AAD_GROUPNAME') in Azure Synapse Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275605/how-to-use-is-memberaad-groupname-in-azure-synapse-analytics?rq=2) this. It is still present?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I access AD Security group in Microsoft Fabric Lakehouse SQL analytics endpoint?

Yes,  `is_member('<AD Group>')`  This function checks the user's membership within the specified Active Directory group, confirming their association within the database's defined principals.

```sql
 SELECT is_member('AAD group name')
```

`is_member(<AD Group>)`  returns:

- 1 if the AD Group is a user in the particular database database and the logged-in user is a member of the AD Group.
- 0 if the AD Group is a user in the particular database and the logged in user is not a member of the AD Group.
- NULL if the AD Group does not exist or is not a user in the database

**Before creating user :-**

[image]

**After creating user in (master) database :-**

[image]

Comment: There is no "CREATE USER" operation in Microsoft Fabric. It is the problem. "CREATE USER is not a supported statement type."